# parse the date with format yyyy.MM.dd HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS with ingest node processor in ELK

Tags: parsing, kibana, logstash-grok, elk

I need to parse `yyyy.MM.dd HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS` format as date field type with ingest node processors.

I couldn't find any applicable grok pattern suitable to parse the above format. And, also the date processor did not work.

example log:

```
[2020.08.31 14:30:23.823121] (INFO) Execution is DONE!
```

How can i parse this log like time:date severity:string message:string ?

Answer (score 1):

Please find below the grok pattern that will parse your logline:

```
\[(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}.%{MONTHNUM}.%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME})\] \(%{LOGLEVEL:log level}\) %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

I have used [Grok Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to debug the grok pattern.

Screenshot of the output after parsing the logline:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but when I applied this, timestamp type is String. I want it date.

Comment: Here, look this post to convert string to date https://discuss.elastic.co/t/converting-string-to-date/26748/5